# values are not saving after refresh the page

Tags: database, multi-vendor, qty-increment

we have marketplace multi vendor/seller site. we gave an option for seller to update the product information through frontend....

As it is marketplace site, we have many sellers.

seller A uploaded product A in frontend.

if seller B have same product , he will assign the same product to his account.

here seller A and seller B can update their respective quantities.

it show updated value when we click on update button, **but once we refresh the page, it show old value only**.

**Phtml**

```
<td>
    <span class="label qty" id="valueqty_<?php echo $assinproducts->getId(); ?>">
        <?php echo intval($assinproducts['qty']); ?>
    </span>

    <input type = "text" id = "qty_<?php echo $assinproducts->getId(); ?>" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" 
    name="stock[]" value="<?php echo intval($assinproducts['qty']); ?>" style="display:none;"/>

    <span class="label wk_action" id="edit_link_<?php echo $assinproducts->getId(); ?>">
        <img onclick="showField('<?php echo $assinproducts->getId(); ?>'); return false;" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('marketplace/images/icon-edit.png'); ?>"/>
    </span>

    <p id="updatedqty_<?php echo $assinproducts->getId(); ?>" style = "display:none;color:red;">Updated</p><br/>

    <button id="update_button_<?php echo $assinproducts->getId(); ?>" class="button wk_mp_btn1" onclick="updateField('<?php echo $assinproducts->getId(); ?>',<?php echo intval($assinproducts['qty']); ?>); return false;" style="display:none" >
        <span>
            <span style="font-size:12px;"><?php echo $helper->__('Update') ?></span>
        </span>
    </button>

    <button id="reset_button_<?php echo $assinproducts->getId(); ?>" type="reset" class="cancel" onclick="hideReset('<?php echo $assinproducts->getId(); ?>'); return false;" style="display:none"></button> 
</td>
```

**Script**

```
function hideReset(product_id)
    {
        var qtyId='#qty_'+ product_id;
        var editLink="#edit_link_"+ product_id;
        var updateButton="#update_button_"+ product_id;
        var resetButton="#reset_button_"+ product_id;

        $wk_jq(qtyId).hide();
        $wk_jq(editLink).show();
        $wk_jq(updateButton).hide();
        $wk_jq(resetButton).hide();
    }

    function showField(product_id)
    {
        var qtyId           = '#qty_'+ product_id;
        var editLink        = "#edit_link_"+ product_id;
        var updateButton    = "#update_button_"+ product_id;
        var resetButton     = "#reset_button_"+ product_id;

        $wk_jq(qtyId).show();
        $wk_jq(editLink).hide();
        $wk_jq(updateButton).show();
        $wk_jq(updateButton).prop('disabled', false);//just in case
        $wk_jq(resetButton).show();

        return false;
    }

    function updateField(product_id,assignqty)
    {
        var qtyId           = '#qty_'+ product_id;
        var valueId         = '#valueqty_'+ product_id;
        var updatedqty      = '#updatedqty_'+ product_id;
        var editLink        = "#edit_link_"+ product_id;
        var updateButton    = "#update_button_"+ product_id;
        var resetButton     = "#reset_button"+ product_id;
        var url             = '<?php echo Mage::getUrl('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/updateField/')?>';

        $wk_jq(qtyId).toggle();
        $wk_jq(editLink).hide();
        $wk_jq(updateButton).show();
        $wk_jq(resetButton).show();

        $qty = $wk_jq(qtyId).val();
        jQuery(valueId).html($qty);
        hideReset(product_id);

        var tmpQty = assignqty+parseInt($qty) ;

        new Ajax.Request(url, {
            method: 'post',
            parameters: {id: product_id, qty: tmpQty},
            onComplete: function (transport) {
                jQuery(priceId).val($price);                
        jQuery(updatedqty).show().delay(2000).fadeOut();
                $updateButton.prop('disabled', false);
            }
        });
    }




</script>
```

**Controllers.php**

```
<?php   

   public function updateFieldAction(){
        $id= $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $selllermpassignproduct=Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->getAssignProDetails($id);
        $customerid=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
        $collection_product = Mage::getModel('marketplace/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('mageproductid',array('eq'=>$id))->addFieldToFilter('userid',array('eq'=>$customerid));
        //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setEditProductId($id);
         $assignqty=isset($selllermpassignproduct['assignqty'])?$selllermpassignproduct['assignqty']:0;
        $newqty=$this->getRequest()->getParam('qty')+$assignqty;
        $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($id);
        $stockItem->setData('manage_stock', 1);
        $stockItem->setData('qty', $newqty);

        $stockItem->save();

        $response['message'] = 'Your Product Is Been Sucessfully Updated';
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response)); 
        //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('marketplace')->__('Your Product Is Been Sucessfully Updated'));
      }
```

Comment: In your controller action, add `echo $newqty; exit();` before saving stock item quantity and try to update value. Are you getting updated value as output? There might be a case new value is not being passed to your controller.

Comment: i added `echo $newqty; exit();` before `$stockItem->save();` but it didt worked for me.

Comment: Could you try to reduce your question to just the relevant lines of code?

Comment: @Elias Thanks a lot for your suggestion, i updated question with relevant code, please  check it.